# Make wave effect for images

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.image{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg')
}

.box-1, .box-2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.image, .content{
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.content{
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"><div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt,</div></div>
  <div class="box-2"><div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.</div>
  <div class="image"></div></div>
</div>
```

From the result above i want to create something like this:

[image]

So the idea is to create rounded corners for both images, but i want to  make the columns connected, so the rounder corners should be connected where i showed the blue line
Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Consider `clip-path` then simply make the flex-basis of the image to be bigger:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.image {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg')
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
}

/* below the added code */
.image {
  flex-basis:70%;
}
.box-1 .image {
 clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 20% 50%);
}
.box-2 .image {
 clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 80% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt,</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

another idea for a responsive version:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

.image {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg')
}

.box-1,
.box-2{
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
  flex:1;
}

/* below the added code */
.image {
  --d:600px;
  flex-basis:calc(50% + 20px);
}
.box-1 .image {
 clip-path: circle(var(--d) at calc(100% - var(--d)) 50%);
}
.box-2 .image {
 clip-path: circle(var(--d) at calc(var(--d)) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt,</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using CSS mask:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

.image {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.wallpaperhub.app/cloudcache/1/b/5/8/e/f/1b58ef6e3d36a42e01992accf5c52d6eea244353.jpg')
}

.box-1,
.box-2{
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
  flex:1;
}

/* below the added code */
.image {
  --d:300px; /* adjust here to control the curve  */
  flex-basis:calc(50% + 43px); /* and here to rectify the gap */
}
.box-1 .image {
 -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--d) at calc(100% - var(--d)) 50%,#fff 99%,transparent);
 -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box-2 .image {
 -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right/calc(100% - var(--d)) 100%,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--d) at var(--d) 50%,#fff 99%,transparent);
 -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt,</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, non. Molestias voluptas velit quae itaque natus nam odio obcaecati minima recusandae enim eos mollitia est animi incidunt, beatae iure perspiciatis.</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice answer, could you take a look here and tell me why the corners of the images are separated? https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-archimedes-b25v8?file=/index.html   i want connected borders. Thanks

Comment: @Asking because the solution I gave is for the width you set. It's not responsive .. check the update for a reponsive solution

Comment: it exists a possibility to make borders more rounded?

Comment: @Asking adjust the values like you want until you get the needed result

Comment: i try this  clip-path: circle(600px at calc(100% - 600px) 75%);, but it does not round borders in the right way

Comment: @Asking no, the only values you need to change are the 600px everywhere and it need to be the same in the 4 places and the pixel value in the flex-basis. that's all .. don't touch anything else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224332/discussion-between-asking-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @Termani Afif, is there a solution without setting `container` styles: .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}? Because if i remove these styles the idea of block dissapears. Could you provide one more example without container settings, just setting the row styles? Thanks